# Help identifying type of texture on walls

Tags: drywall, texture

Probably a dumb question, but I'm having trouble determining if these walls are orange peel or knockdown textures. The first two photos below are in the same room, but at the minimum seem like completely different consistencies for the texture. The last photo is a different room in the house.

For the second photo, it looks like orange peel to me, while the first and last I can go either way. Anyone with more experience care to educate me? Thanks!

[image: Wall 3]
[image: Wall 2]
[image: Wall 1]

Answer (score 2):

Top two are orange peel, bottom is knockdown. You can tell that it's knockdown by the presence of the large flat areas (where it was "knocked down" with a trowel).

Comment: Agree about numbers 2 and 3. Might think maybe that 1 is another knockdown.

Comment: Agree with @AloysiusDefenestrate that 1 and 3 are knockdown (also sometimes called brocade). 2 is orange peel

Answer (score 0):

Honestly the only one that is clearly done right is the 3rd one being splatter knockdown.

1. Looks like heavy **orange peel** texture and it was **sanded and knocked down**. In some areas the **texture has runs** probably from being **too wet when sprayed**.
2. Looks like **orange peel** without enough texture sprayed on.
3. Clearly **splatter knockdown** and was done properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think norcaljohnny's assessment is spot on. You can see the lines where it was either sanded, or those could be brush strokes. Either way, it's evidence of a touch up. Orange peel and knockdown are very similar, with the biggest difference being orange peel is applied with a spray gun, and knockdown is typically applied by hand. What I think you are looking at is a homeowner tried to patch the wall, and replicate the orange peel, but without the spray gun, it winds up looking like knockdown. If that's the case, the homeowner actually did a not-so-bad job. I have seen people just leave the patch flat! :D (my comment is about pic #1)